# Make listview content become part of superview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a modal view where I am adding some widgets and a listview. The content of the modal view will require scrolling and I want listview to scroll along with other data. Currently listview is scrolling because of long content in a fix size but other content is not scrolling with it. Following is my code:

```
    Widget taxDeclarationUI() {
        return Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(25.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(25.0),
              ),
            ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                titleText(),
                taxInfoListView(),
                confirmationCheckbox()
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

Widget titleText() {
    return Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: Text(
      "Declaration of financial information",
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
    ),) ;
  }

  Widget taxInfoListView() {
    return ListView.builder(itemCount: taxResidencyList.length,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => TaxDetailItem(
          taxResidence: taxResidencyList[index],
          textEditingController: controllers[index],
          countrySelectionChanged: getUpdatedCountryCode,
          index: index,
          taxCountryRemove: removeTaxCountry),);
  }

  Widget confirmationCheckbox() {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Checkbox(
            value: checkedValue,
            onChanged: (newVal) {
              setState(() {
                checkedValue = newVal ?? false;
              });
            }),
        Expanded(
          child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                elevation: 0,
                side: BorderSide(width: 0, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              onPressed: () => {
                setState(() {
                  checkedValue = !checkedValue;
                })
              },
              child: const Text(
                'I confirm that above tax residancy and US self-declaration is true and accurate.',
                maxLines: 4,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
              )),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

My goal is to expand the complete listview inside the parent scrollview and it should only scroll with other content of parent scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SingleChildScrollView + Column, you can try CustomScrollView.

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: titleText(),
    ),
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        childCount: taxResidencyList.length,
        (context, index) => TaxDetailItem(
          taxResidence: taxResidencyList[index],
          textEditingController: controllers[index],
          countrySelectionChanged: getUpdatedCountryCode,
          index: index,
          taxCountryRemove: removeTaxCountry,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: confirmationCheckbox(),
    ),
  ],
);
```